# For batch files, how to add a newline character to promptString when using "set"?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm creating a simple batch file to auto-set paths for Java. Below is the code I currently have. I want to add a number of newlines after the promptString for "java_path" in line 2 before the input. Help please?

```
@echo off
set /p java_path=Enter path to Java installation folder, including quotation marks (eg: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"): 
setx -m JAVA_HOME %java_path%
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%java_path:"=%\bin";
```

Resolved after Compo's comment. My original thought was that with "@echo off" that any "echo"s after that line would not work... obviously I didn't understand the command at all.

```
@echo off
echo Enter path to Java installation folder, including quotation marks (eg: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"):
echo(
set /p java_path=
setx -m JAVA_HOME %java_path%
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%java_path:"=%\bin";
```

Comment: `Echo(` will print an empty line, so insert `Echo(` at line `3`, and insert `Echo(` at line `4`. If you atually want the end user to type their input underneath the prrompt string, use `Echo Enter path to Java installation folder, including quotation marks` on line `2`, use `Echo (eg: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1")` on line `3`, use `Echo(` on line `4`, and use `Set /P "=> "` on line `5`.

Comment: Perfect. Fixed the code while you were updating your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to submit your answer to the post so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the methodology in my comment:

```sh
@Echo Off
:Ask
Set "java_path="
Echo Enter path to Java installation folder,
Echo  excluding quotation marks
Echo  (eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1)
Echo(
Set /P "java_path=> "
If Not Defined java_path GoTo Ask
PushD "%java_path%" 2> NUL || GoTo Ask
Set "java_path=%CD%"
PopD
Echo %java_path%
Pause
```

As a more complicated alternative, which will only work if the entered path should not contain any exclamation marks:

```sh
@Echo Off
(Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
) & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Ask
Set "java_path="
Set /P "java_path=Enter path to Java installation folder,!LF! excluding quotation marks!LF! (eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1)!LF!!LF!> "
If Not Defined java_path GoTo Ask
PushD "%java_path%" 2> NUL && (Set "java_path=!CD!" & PopD) || GoTo Ask
Echo %java_path%
Pause
EndLocal
```

I am not including the 'admin' `setx` commands, because I do not believe that it is necessary to modify the `%Path%` environment variable, and you should never, ever, use `setx.exe` to do so.

Because the `%Path%` variable is special, unlike standard variables, it contains the values from both the System and User environments. As soon as you use `%Path%` with `/M`, you are permanently adding content from the User's `Path` to the System `Path`. When you later `Echo %Path%`, you'll see that you have duplicate entries of all of the previous User `Path` variable content.